# API polling bot on heroku

Tags: ruby, rubygems, heroku, bots

I want to create a bot which makes API request per minute to some API url. This then needs to ping a particular user if data entry has changed against his name in the API feed. I want to go for a free solution on Heroku. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, heroku supports thin as a web server, which is EventMachine enabled, so an easy way to do this is to write a quick sinatra app and use EM.add_periodic_timer for your API calls. When you deploy this sinatra app to heroku, it'll use thin by default, so there's no extra configuration needed. You can test via `thin start -p 4567` assuming your config.ru is correct. Here's a pretty standard one, assuming your app is in app.rb:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require :default
require File.expand_path('app', File.dirname(__FILE__))

run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: I should note that if you want the sinatra app to still be responsive, check out em-http-request for making the calls. If you don't like callbacks, check out em-synchrony and sinatra-synchrony

Answer (score 2):

I currently check the status of some sites for free on heroku. The secret? Rufus-Scheduer.

Install the gem

```
 gem install rufus-scheduler
```

Make sure you include the gem in bundler or however you are including it.

Then you need to create a file called `task_scheduler.rb` and stick this in you `initializers` directory.

```
 require 'rufus/scheduler'
 scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

 scheduler.every '1m' do
    url = "http://codeglot.com"
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    #do stuff with response.body
 end
```

If you have any trouble you can see this blog post:

http://intridea.com/2009/2/13/dead-simple-task-scheduling-in-rails?blog=company

Comment: I dont want to make a rails app. Sinatra is fine but No Rails. Rails would be overkill.

Comment: How is it overkill. I could literally get this up on a new up in 5 min.

Comment: I would personally prefer Sinatra rather than RAils.